# Epplus OpenXml unable to find index in range

Tags: excel, range, interop, epplus

Need to find the index of each in r (range). Please help

Code:

```
r = "C1:G10"
//Interop : 
ws.Range[ws.Cells[r[1, 1].Row, r[1, 1].Column], ws.Cells[r[1, 1].Row, r[1, r.Columns.Count].Column]]
```

How to get the index **r[1,1]** in Epplus like used above in interop.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure I follow the question, but EPPlus has a few means of referencing a given range.

A couple of examples:

```
using (var xl = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo("input.xlsx")))
{
    var wks = xl.Workbook.Worksheets.First();

    var rangeByAddress = wks.Cells["C1:G10"];
    var rangeByIndexAndDimensions = wks.Cells[1,3,10,7]; //[row, col, numberOfRows, numberOfCols]
}
```

you can then convert this to an array of objects representing the values of the cells like this:

```
var values = rangeByAddress.Value as object[,];
```

Comment: now like for example: for the data values stored in rangeByAddress like below in a bucket of 5x5 : C1xG10 : [ 20 ,30 ..10 : 30 20 ..50] how to access individual values/position based on index like rangeByAddress[1,1] would give 20 like an array ie: when index starts from 1

Comment: how to get rows and columns of that index? tried something like this : `rangeByAddress.Rows as object[,]` its gives conversion error _"Cannot convert type 'int' to 'object[,]' via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion"_

Comment: *Q1)* I'm puzzled what's the alternative for Excel.XlDirection.xlUp in Epplus just couldn't find it ? *Q2)* Whats the difference between ExcelRangeBase vs ExcelRange?

Comment: anyone can please guide?